# Is this solvable: $x^{2}\equiv5\pmod{229}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$$x^{2}\equiv5\pmod{229}.$$

Using Legendre symbol,

$(\frac{5}{229})(\frac{229}{5})=(-1)^{\frac{4}{2}*\frac{228}{2}}=(-1)^{2*114}=(-1)^{228}=1.$
Hence, 5 is a quadratic residue $mod(229)$ if 229 is a quadratic
residue $mod(5).$ Thus, $x^{2}\equiv229mod(5)\equiv4mod(5).$ We
can use 2 as a primitive root of $mod(5)$ to see that $2^{2}\equiv4mod(5).$
So we need to solve $2i\equiv2mod(4).$ The $gcd(2,4)=2$ and $2\mid2.$
Hence, there are two solutions $mod(229)$ or $mod(5).$

$ $

Is my solution correct?

Comment: You wrote too much. Since $5$ has shape $4k+1$, we have $(5/229)=(229/5)$. But $(229/5)=(4/5)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The initial part looks good to me. Maybe I'm missing something here, but what is the purpose of the last little bit? I would just end it at $2^2 \equiv 4\pmod{5}$ and so 229 is a quadratic residue mod 5 and hence 5 is a quadratic residue mod 229.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of the equation

$$x^2\equiv 5\ (mod\ 229)$$

are

x = 66

and

x = 163

Comment: how did you come up with those two solutions? My two solutions only work for $\pmod{5}$

Comment: In GP, "for(i=0,228,if((i^2) % 229==5,print(i)))" yields 66 and 163, so that is one way to get this result.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means..

Comment: @user80979 It is code that you can use with the software GP to produce all the solutions to your congruence equation.

Comment: Is it possible to deduce those solutions $mod(1009)$ from the solutions $mod(7)$?